# how to get only item details to next activity to edit

Tags: android

in a list of bluetooth devices item names are renamed and stored in database.when the app starts it should check the database and if uuids are same then it should display the item list with those names.when i click on item and goes to next activity and i click on settings option  to edit name of that item and comes back and back to first activty.it changes the name but all the names in the listview are changed to edited name and all names are same i got.

```
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    final BluetoothDevice device = mLeDeviceListAdapter.getDevice(position);
    if (device == null) return;
    Log.v("_____________LOG", "localdevicename : "+mBluetoothAdapter.getName()+" localdeviceAddress : "+mBluetoothAdapter.getAddress());


    Log.v("___________LOG", "localdevicename : "+mBluetoothAdapter.getName()+" localdeviceAddress : "+mBluetoothAdapter.getAddress());
    UUID deviceUuid = new UUID(device.hashCode(), ((long)device.hashCode() << 32)  );
    Log.v("__________DEVICE UUID________","__________________"+deviceUuid);
    String deviceUUID = deviceUuid.toString();
    Log.v("_______________________","___________________"+deviceUUID);

     Intent intent = new Intent(this, DeviceControlActivity.class);

     intent.putExtra(DeviceControlActivity.EXTRAS_DEVICE_NAME, sname);
     intent.putExtra(DeviceControlActivity.EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS, device.getAddress());//}
     intent.putExtra(DeviceControlActivity.EXTRAS_DEVICE_UUID, deviceUUID);//}
         if (mScanning) {
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        mScanning = false;
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}

    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        // General ListView optimization code.
        if (view == null) {
            view = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.listitem_device, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.deviceAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
            viewHolder.deviceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        BluetoothDevice device = mLeDevices.get(i);
        String deviceName = device.getName();
        UUID deviceUuid = new UUID(device.hashCode(), ((long)device.hashCode() << 32)  );
        Log.v("__________DEVICE UUID________","__________________"+deviceUuid);
        String deviceId = deviceUuid.toString();
        Log.v("_______________________","___________________"+deviceId);

        if (deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 0){
             db.open();
        if(db!=null)
        {
             Cursor c=db.getData();
             String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM DeviceDetails";
                c = db.select(selectQuery);
                while (c != null && c.moveToNext())
                {
          if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
         if(deviceId.equalsIgnoreCase(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("uuid"))))
                    {
                          viewHolder.deviceName.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("devicename")));
sname= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("devicename"));
                    }
             else
                     {
                          mBluetoothAdapter.setName("NONAME");           
                     }

                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }      
        }
        }
        db.close();
        }
        else
            viewHolder.deviceName.setText(R.string.unknown_device);
        viewHolder.deviceAddress.setText(device.getAddress());

        return view;
    }
}
```

**from this class it calls the following class and in this i added setting option.from above code it should get the item selected name and uuid of device.**in this i should get only the item  details i selected.

```
             mDeviceName = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRAS_DEVICE_NAME);
    mDeviceAddress = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
    mDeviceUUID=intent.getStringExtra(EXTRAS_DEVICE_UUID);
    Log.v("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", "__________________________________________"+mDeviceUUID);
```

case R.id.menu_settings:

```
    Log.v("_______mdevicename______", ""+mDeviceName);
    Log.v("_______device uuid______", ""+mDeviceUUID);

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditPreview.class);
         intent.putExtra("Dname", mDeviceName);
            intent.putExtra("Daddress", mDeviceUUID);
            startActivityForResult(intent,0);

            return true;
```

and the following is my edit class in this it adds to database and when i click on edittext it giving the device name of fistrow but not item selected name.and after movig back to fist activity all name in list shows the same name.

```
              protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_layout);
    edittext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.device_text);
     db = new DataBaseAdapter(this);

     Intent i = getIntent();


       if(i.hasExtra("Dname"))
             val = i.getStringExtra("Dname");

    edittext.setText(val);
    if(i.hasExtra("Daddress"))
        pos=i.getStringExtra("Daddress");
  db.open();

 db.insertData(pos,val,"off","off");

     c = db.getData();
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    db.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){

        db.open();
        c=db.getData();

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                    String strSQL = "UPDATE DeviceDetails SET devicename ='"+ edittext.getText().toString() +"'  WHERE uuid = '"+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("uuid"))+"'" ;
                    db.select(strSQL);
                db.updateData(pos, edittext.getText().toString());

                Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("Dname", edittext.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("Daddress",pos);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

    db.close();

    super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: Why dont you try with the unique id to the next activity and update ?

Comment: Also its not safe to perform a database pull operation in getView()

Comment: uuid i unique id only when i move next activity i am get first row devicename with any uuid

Comment: String strSQL = "UPDATE DeviceDetails SET devicename ='"+ edittext.getText().toString() +"'  WHERE uuid = '"+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("uuid"))+"'" ; I think this is where the problem is . Since the update query is with in the do while loop you are setting value for devicename  in with every uuid .  WHERE uuid = '"This should be the selected uuid"'

Comment: how to solve. i should remove do while loop?say i am new to this

Comment: public long updateRemark(  String remarkid, String remark )
    {
     
     /**
      * remarkid  Unique iD
      * remark    Field to be changed
      */
      
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put( KEY_REMARKS, remark );

  
        return  sqLiteDb.update(TABLE_NAME, values,KEY_REMARKID + "='" + remarkid + "'", null);
    }

Comment: where i should write this

Comment: its a function that updates "remark" field of a table with its remarkid. You can change it to according to your need.And call it in onBackPressed()

Comment: i done but no use when i click other device to edit i got previous devicename only.

Comment: uninstall the app and try?

Comment: i did like this to send devicename but the query going to edittext not the name     db=new DataBaseAdapter(this);
             db.open();
             Cursor c=db.getData();
                String strSQL = "SELECT devicename from DeviceDetails WHERE uuid = '"+mDeviceUUID+"'" ;
      db.select(strSQL);
      mDeviceName=strSQL;
          db.close();
and in database adapter i codded as the following to get the details of user required.
         public Cursor getData(){
   return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {UUID,DEVICENAME,LIGHT,ALARM,
     }, null, null, null, null, null);
  }

Comment: i did uninstall and doing while running